# How to zip values in two dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, zip

I have 2 dictionaries:

```
{('x0', '0'): 'x0', ('x0', '1'): 'x1', ('x1', '0'): 'x1', ('x1', '1'): 'x0'}
```

and

```
{('y0', '0'): 'y1', ('y0', '1'): 'y1', ('y1', '0'): 'y0', ('y1', '1'): 'y0'}
```

and I want to zip them in the way so that the result would be:

```
{(('x0','y0'), 0) : ('x0','y1'), 
(('x0', 'y0'), 1) : ('x1, 'y1')... and so on}
```

What is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python3.7 dictionaries are ordered, thus, you can iterate over `dict.items()`:

```
d1 = {('x0', '0'): 'x0', ('x0', '1'): 'x1', ('x1', '0'): 'x1', ('x1', '1'): 'x0'}
d2 = {('y0', '0'): 'y1', ('y0', '1'): 'y1', ('y1', '0'): 'y0', ('y1', '1'): 'y0'}
new_d = {((c, d), b):(a, e) for ([c, b], a), ([d, _], e) in zip(d1.items(), d2.items())}
```

Output:

```
{(('x0', 'y0'), '0'): ('x0', 'y1'), (('x0', 'y0'), '1'): ('x1', 'y1'), (('x1', 'y1'), '0'): ('x1', 'y0'), (('x1', 'y1'), '1'): ('x0', 'y0')}
```

However, this solution will only work in Python3.7. For use in any other versions, consider utilizing `collections.OrderedDict` or implementing the structure as a list of tuples to ensure that proper pairing always occurs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not *quite* sure what you're getting at, but the following does something like what you're describing:

```
a = {('x0', '0'): 'x0', ('x0', '1'): 'x1', ('x1', '0'): 'x1', ('x1', '1'): 'x0'}
b = {('y0', '0'): 'y1', ('y0', '1'): 'y1', ('y1', '0'): 'y0', ('y1', '1'): 'y0'}
{((x[0], y[0]), x[1]): (a[x], b[y]) for x, y in zip(a.keys(), b.keys())}
>> {(('x0', 'y0'), '0'): ('x0', 'y1'), (('x0', 'y0'), '1'): ('x1', 'y1'), (('x1', 'y1'), '0'): ('x1', 'y0'), (('x1', 'y1'), '1'): ('x0', 'y0')}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Ajax1234 mentioned, before Python 3.7, `dict.items` isn't ordered, but that doesn't mean you can't sort it yourself!

Confirming that it's unordered (Python 3.5)

```
In [132]: list(zip(x.items(), y.items()))
Out[132]:
[((('x0', '0'), 'x0'), (('y0', '1'), 'y1')),
 ((('x1', '0'), 'x1'), (('y1', '0'), 'y0')),
 ((('x0', '1'), 'x1'), (('y0', '0'), 'y1')),
 ((('x1', '1'), 'x0'), (('y1', '1'), 'y0'))]
```

Explicitly ordering it

```
In [129]: list(zip(sorted(x.items()), sorted(y.items())))
Out[129]:
[((('x0', '0'), 'x0'), (('y0', '0'), 'y1')),
 ((('x0', '1'), 'x1'), (('y0', '1'), 'y1')),
 ((('x1', '0'), 'x1'), (('y1', '0'), 'y0')),
 ((('x1', '1'), 'x0'), (('y1', '1'), 'y0'))]
```

Creating your new `dict`

```
In [131]: {((x0, y0), x1): (x, y) for ((x0, x1), x), ((y0, y1), y) in zip(sorted(x.items()), sorted(y.items()))}

Out[131]:
{(('x0', 'y0'), '0'): ('x0', 'y1'),
 (('x0', 'y0'), '1'): ('x1', 'y1'),
 (('x1', 'y1'), '0'): ('x1', 'y0'),
 (('x1', 'y1'), '1'): ('x0', 'y0')}
```